# Which of the following is true for the following linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformation on $V_2(\Bbb R)$ by $T_1(a,b)=(0,a)$ and $T_2(a,b)=(a,0)$ , then which of the following is true

1) $T_1T_2=0$

2)$T_1^2=T_1$

3)$T_2^2=T_1$

4)$T_1T_2 $ is not  equal to $0$

> I've got the matrix representation of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are as follows

$T_1=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ and$T_2=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$ 
On substituting I've got 4) as true... Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all false except 4. You don't need to use the matrix representations.

Example: For 1 and 4, $T_1(T_2(a,b)) = T_1(a,0) = (0,a)$